# generators + promises to parallelize N number of items

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, generator, q

the challenge:

1. We want to make N parallel ajax requests for an item's children.
2. Upon returning, we want to process them in sequential order (1...N)
3. We do NOT want to wait for all promises to return, but we want to process them IN ORDER as they come back.

**For example:**

Even if 2,3,5 come back before 1, we should hold onto the results of 2,3,5, and upon 1's return, process 1,2,3 in order (and wait for 4 to come back before 5)

Tools: Q + ES6 generators

Create array of N-1 length with placeholder variables

EG when N = 3:

```
let [N1,N2,N3] = yield [ Promise1, Promise2, Promise3 ]

//process items sequentially:
   console.log(N1)
   console.log(N2)
   console.log(N3)
```

However, populating an array of empty variables doesn't seem to work of course because the reference doesn't know where to find the var declaration

```
for(var i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
   res.push("some empty var")
}
```

Given the constraints of sticking to the tools provided, how could we parallelize calls, but process their returns sequentially?

Comment: What are `AJAX1`, `AJAX2` and etc? Are they promises?

Comment: yes you can assume promises

Comment: okay. so you'd extend the chain N number of times? What about for 20?

Comment: Pity you're not using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by waiting for the next promise inside the loop:

```
const promises = […]; // or created programmatically
for (const promise of promises) {
    const result = yield promise; // await them sequentially
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Is it really `yield` to be used there? It's not obvious who and how is supposed to iterate over the generator then.

Comment: Why is this necessary? `Promise.all()` returns expected result described at Question

Comment: @zerkms: OP will run this inside `Q.async(function* () {…})`

Comment: @guest271314 It's a bit hidden in the question, but the expected result is that "*[with 2 and 3 already arrived] upon 1's return, it processes 1,2,3 in order [without waiting] for 4*". The `all` solution doesn't do that.

Comment: @Bergi Where did you locate requirement _"[without waiting] for 4"_ at Question?

Comment: Editing now. My fault

Comment: @Bergi - how is const promises constructed? Does pushing promises into an array necessarily send them though?

Comment: @Bergi Do you mean `console.log(result);`? without `s`

Comment: Ah I see. Okay so you'd have a function that pushes N promises into an array and then loop over the results with yield to process their return.

Comment: @AnthonyChung Yes, `push` them into the array, use `map` or whatever, just create them so that they start running in parallel. Not sure what you mean by "send them".

Comment: @Bergi `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` referencing `yield`?

Comment: @Bergi No. used same function used for own Answer

Comment: @guest271314: You're writing a generator function that is run by Q's coroutine methods?

Comment: @Bergi No, not that either, which probably explains.

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, I occasionally paste the snippets from my answers into the console to test them, and accidentally press enter without substituting `…` for test data :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise.all()`, `.then()`

`javascript` at Answer returns exact results described at Question

> 1. We want to make N parallel ajax requests for an item's children.
> 2. Upon returning, we want to process them in sequential order (1...N)
> 3. We do NOT want to wait for all promises to return, but we want to process them IN ORDER as they come back.
>      how could we parallelize calls, but process their returns
>      sequentially?

You can use `.then()` chained to original function which returns a promise or `Promise` object itself to process promise before `return`ing value to be processed in sequential order of parameters passed to `Promise.all()` at `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()`

```js
var n = 0;
var fn = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("promise " + ++n + " called");
    setTimeout(function(i) {
      resolve(i)
    }, Math.random() * 2500, n)
  })
  // handle requirement 3. here
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    return res
  })
}

Promise.all([fn(), fn(), fn()]) // handle requirement 1. here
// handle requirement 2. here
.then(function(data) {
    let [N1, N2, N3] = data;
    console.log(N1, N2, N3);
})
```

Comment: I thought about that too. But Promise.all will only proceed once ALL the ajax calls return. We want all AJAX calls fired at once, and then process them in order as they return.

Comment: All ajax calls would be fired at once using `Promise.all()`

Comment: "downvote" description? How does `javascript` at Answer not meet requirement _"1. We want to make N parallel ajax requests for an item's children.
2. Upon returning, we want to process them in sequential order (1...N)"_ , _"how could we parallelize calls, but process their returns sequentially?"_ ?

Comment: What is purpose of "downvote"? `javascript` at Answer meets requirement described at Question

Comment: spec: Even if 2,3,5 come back before 1, we should hold onto the results of 2,3,5, and upon 1's return, process 1,2,3 in order (and wait for 4 to come back before 5). Promise.all will wait for 1,2,3,4,5 to resolve before processing them even though all 5 calls are made

Comment: @AnthonyChung Yes, `javascript` at Answer achieves this. You can chain `.then()` to original promise, process promise value, then process again in order at `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()`. See updated post

Comment: spec also says that you need to generalize for N number of AJAX calls

Comment: @AnthonyChung What do you mean by "generalize"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121219/discussion-between-anthony-chung-and-guest271314).

Comment: upvoted because this answers original question correctly, just use a loop when `Promise.all` returns to handle N number of calls

Comment: Again, the original spec said that we need to process as they come back. Promise.all waits for all to come back before processing. Right under where it said "for example"

Comment: @AnthonyChung Have you reviewed comments and tried stacksnippets? `.then()` chained to original promise is process when the `Promise` is fulfilled or rejected, before reaching `.then()` at `Promise.all()`. See updated post, removed initial example to avoid confusion concerning updated Question. Comments at `javascript` at Answer reference requirements described at both original and updated Question.

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, but those `then` callbacks are not sequential.

Comment: @Bergi Not certain how the callbacks can be both processed in sequential order and _"3. We do NOT want to wait for all promises to return, but we want to process them IN ORDER as they come back."_? What is meant by "sequential order" here? The first `.then()` chained to function returning promise processes "as they come back". The array returned at `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()` will be in sequential order reflecting original array passed to `Promise.all()`

Comment: It means that callback 1 waits for promise 1, callback 2 waits for promises 1 and 2, callback 3 waits for promises 1, 2 and 3, and so on.

Comment: @Bergi _"It means that callback 1 waits for promise 1, callback 2 waits for promises 1 and 2, callback 3 waits for promises 1, 2 and 3, and so on."_ Did not gather the same requirement from text of Question, here. Though, `Promise.all()`, `.then()` pattern can be used to achieve the same

Comment: After the comments by the OP it should be clear that is what he wants. And imo from the question text as well.